# Screen scrape to email with full url for images and css

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, screen-scraping

I am screen scraping a webpage and sending it as a html email.

What is the easiest/best way to manipulate the html to set full http addresses for all images and css files?

Current method is similar to (manually typed) + this is very open to error.

```
string html = rawHtml.replace("=\"", "=\"" + Request["SERVER_NAME"]);
```

.
.

Here is the current function we use to screen scrape using GET

```
public static string WebGet(string address)
{
    string result = "";
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address)))
        {
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            result = s;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: So you want to resolve relative URLs to absolute URLs, i.e. `img src="/images/img.jpg"` becomes `img src="http://example.com/images/img.jpg`, and similar for CSS (and links)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is an HTML parser. Once you parse the html string with the parser, you can execute commands that easily manipulate the DOM, and thus you could find all img elements, check their src and append the Request["SERVER_NAME"] if you need to.

I don't code in ASP, but I found this:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

And here is a useful article I found explaining how to use it:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx